# Twitter Bot Node.js and Twit Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots, node.js-stream

**PROBLEM**

So im trying to create a twitter bot and everything was going fine until i tried to auto reply to users who follow me. 
I'am learning and was watching from this tutorial [Coding Train Twitter Bot(LINK)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvsqQjwrISQ&index=5&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6atTSxoRiVnSuOn6JHnq2yV) but i seem to get this [error(PHOTO)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSDRI.png) even tho i did everything exactly the same.

***Im Using***:

- Node.js
- NPM
- Windows CMD Command Prompt
- Sublime Text 3

**Importing Packages**

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var Keys = require('./private_auth_keys');
var T = new Twit(Keys);
```

**Stream Setup**.

I belive the bug is somewhere in the stream part but i dont get it... i did everything the same as the video. Maybe twitter blocked this from their API? idk what im talking about, but any feedback would be awesome.

```
var stream = T.stream('user');


stream.on('follow', followed);


function followed(eventMsg) {
    console.log("New Follower Reply Sent!");

    var Name = eventMsg.source.name;
    var screenName = eventMsg.source.screen_name;



tweetIt('Heyyy .@' + screenName + ' thanks for the follow! Do you like memes? #RateThatMeme');
}
```

**Reply/Tweet Function**

```
function tweetIt(txt) {


var tweet = {
status: txt
}


T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);


function tweeted(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("oof! Something went wrong!");
    } else {
         console.log("Tweet sent successfully!");

    }
  } 
}
```

***Error Message***

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Bad Twitter streaming request: 401
    at Object.exports.makeTwitError (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projects Code Train\node\node2\node_modules\twit\lib\helpers.js:74:13)....etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter user streams were retired in August so this code will no longer work as is.

Answer (score 1):

401 status code means you are not unauthenticated - there should be additional `WWW-Authenticate` header in response that will tell you more.

I think twitter API changed since this tutorial was recorded and you have to do a bit more now to be able to access it, this is probably a reason for 401 status. as far as I can see, [the author moved to mastodon with this tutorial lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKSxBd56H70&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6byiVX7_Z1rclitVhMBmNFQ) because of that.